# Screen + vim causes shift-enter to insert 'M' and a newline

Tags: vim, ide, editor, gnu-screen

When running a vim instance in gnu screen hitting shift enter in insert mode adds an 'M' and then a newline, rather than just a newline.

Does anybody know what the problem might be, or where to look?

Relevant system info:

> Ubuntu 8.04.1
>
> Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
>
> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled Jan 31 2008 12:20:21)
>     Included patches: 1-138
>
> Konsole 1.6.6 (Using KDE 3.5.10)

Thanks to the comments.  When checking the value of `$TERM` I noticed that it was `xterm` (as expected), but within screen `$TERM` was set to `screen-bce`.  Setting `TERM=xterm` after launching screen resolves this issue.

Adding the following to `~/.screenrc` solved the problem without having to do anything manually:

> term xterm

Comment: you might want to specify what's your terminal settings, as I think it can be the issue

Comment: You were absolutely right.  I had failed to notice that $TERM (normally xterm) was set to screen-bce in my screen session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing info from your question:

1. Where do you run screen and see this issue? Some terminal app (KTerminal, Gnome terminal, virtual console etc) or remote session (eg putty, ssh from another computer)
2. do a “echo $TERM” and tell us its output
3. do a “cat -v”, press Shift-Enter, then Enter, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and then tell us what is output.

Comment: cat -v care to expand on this little treasure?

Comment: cat -v will display control codes in a readable format. In this case, if his terminal outputs control codes when Shift-Enter is pressed, they will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could fix your $TERM for within konsole.  Install "ncurses-term" and configure konsole to set $TERM=konsole-256color.  Then configure screen with "term screen-256color".  Or 'konsole' and 'screen', respectively, if that's your preference.  Konsole and screen are *not* xterm and doesn't support everything xterm does, so using incorrect $TERM can lead to bad things.