# Pressing <Enter> gives me an "M" at the beginning of the line

Tags: vim, vi, ncurses, gnu-screen

This is a most strange problem, which I only get it using GNU Screen and a Nokia N900. Under vi (both vim and nvi, it turns out) if I type in insert mode `one<Enter>two` I get

```
Mtwo
one
```

So, not only does `<Enter>` put an `M` at the beginning of the line, but actually it does something pretty weird in the meantime. Among other things, this issue doesn't let me save and exit.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

**POSSIBLE ANSWER**: It turns out [I wasn't the only one having this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378/screen-vim-causes-shift-enter-to-insert-m-and-a-newline), which is gone (at least in our case) by simply adding `term xterm` to your `.screenrc`. Sorry for not doing a more thorough search before asking...

Comment: `^M` is the representation of a carriage return, usually found in text files with Windows line endings. Just an idea…

Comment: Yes, I thought about it too, though I my issue was missing the caret. Thanks.

Comment: (Restarting terminal emulator (In my case, terminator) did the job for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<Enter>` is like a carriage return and linefeed (`<CRLF>`). That's ASCII 10, followed by ASCII 13 (which is the CTRL-M you see). The screen, however, isn't supporting it. Try to do:

```
export TERM=vt100
```

then run vi, etc or just

```
TERM=vt100 vi
```

which should fix the behavior (assuming you have vt100 terminal capabilities).

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, though it didn't quite work for me, but you were on the right track. Please refer to my edit.